# Fluid Image 80% width and height relative to its parent vertically and horizontally aligned

Tags: css

Height was not respected on this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HvM8E/1/)

I want the image to have a height and width of 80% relative to its parent, vertically and horizontally aligned. For some reason, it does not work.

HTML:

```
<div id="menu_header_new_orig">
    <img id="menu_logo_orig" src="https://imagizer.imageshack.us/v2/849x565q90/833/uua2.jpg" />
</div>
```

CSS:

```
    #menu_header_new_orig {
        margin-top: 2.5%;
        height:40%;
        width:100%;
        overflow: hidden;
        position: relative;
        border: 1px solid green;
        text-align: center;
    }
    #menu_logo_orig {
        width: 80%;
        height: 80%;
        position: relative;
    }
```

I have figured it out [here](http://jsfiddle.net/HvM8E/15/), but just in case somebody have better solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**If** I understand you correct :

The parent `#menu_header_new_orig` own parent must also have a height (obviously 100%)

```
html, body {
    height: 100%;
}
```

set display to inline, 10% top to get vertical alignment

```
#menu_logo_orig {
    top: 10%;
    display: inline;
    position: relative;
    width: 80%;
    height: 80%;
}
```

Is that what you were heading for? [not really sure] - try to set `#menu_header_new_orig` height to other things than `40%` to get it in another perspective.

forked fiddle -> **http://jsfiddle.net/Dmc7j/**

Comment: Your fiddle looks great. Thanks.

Comment: @JunM, happy if that was what you wanted :)